# Android 10 wifimanager.getNetworkSuggestions() is crashing the app

Tags: android, kotlin

I have android 10 device, in which i am trying to get the existing network suggestions if any, so i am doing the code in that way:

```
val existingPasspointSuggestions = wifiManager.networkSuggestions
            .filter { wifiNetworkSuggestion ->
                wifiNetworkSuggestion.passpointConfig != null
            }
```

But this is crashing with following message :

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getNetworkSuggestions()Ljava/util/List; in class Landroid/net/wifi/WifiManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.net.wifi.WifiManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)

I am refering this document : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-suggest
which is saying suggestion API is available from 10 and higher.

This code is working correctly in Android 11.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I Found one thing, WifiManager class has getNetworkSuggestions() method which is available from API 30 and higher, while the WifiNetworkSuggestion class was added in API 29 and higher. WifiManager Class method link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getNetworkSuggestions().                     WifiNetworkSuggestion class link : https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/wifi/WifiNetworkSuggestion

Answer (score 0):

You're saying correctly that `WifiNetworkSuggestion` API for auto-connecting to predefined Wi-Fi networks was added in API 29 (Android 10). Unfortunately, method [`getNetworkSuggestions()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getnetworksuggestions) was added in API 30:
[image: Android documentation of method getNetworkSuggestions()]

Comment: is there any other way to get this in Android 10

Comment: can we use wifiManager.configuredNetwork in android 10 and below version, as network suggestion not available in android 10.

Answer (score 0):

The `getNetworkSuggestions()` method was added in API level 30, which is Android 11. It is not available in previous versions of the Android SDK.

If you are targeting API level 29 or lower, you will not be able to use `getNetworkSuggestions()` directly. However, there is a workaround that you can use to achieve similar functionality. You can create a foreground service and call `startForeground()` on the service to display a persistent notification. In the notification, you can include an action that, when clicked, launches the Wi-Fi settings activity. The user can then manually add the Wi-Fi network to their device's list of saved networks.

Here is an example implementation of this workaround:

```
public class NetworkSuggestionService extends Service {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Notification notification = createNotification();
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private Notification createNotification() {
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, settingsIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Add Wi-Fi network")
                .setContentText("Tap to add a new Wi-Fi network")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In this example, the createNotification() method creates a notification that includes an action that launches the Wi-Fi settings activity. The onStartCommand() method starts the foreground service and displays the notification.

Note that this workaround requires the user to manually add the Wi-Fi network to their device's list of saved networks, whereas `getNetworkSuggestions()` allows your app to programmatically suggest a Wi-Fi network to the device. If you require this functionality, you will need to target API level 30 or higher.